# RegEx - No sequentially spaces

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to achieve these tasks through RegEx:

1. The string must start with alphabet.
2. String can have maximum length of 30 characters.
3. String may contain Numbers, Alphabets and Space ( ).
4. String may be case-insensitive.
5. String should not have more than one space sequentially.
6. String cannot end with Space.

After going through RegEx wiki and other RegEx questions, I've this expression:

`/^([A-Z])([A-Z0-9 ]){0,29}$/i`

Although, This successfully achieves task 1-4, I'm unable to find anything on task 5 and 6.

Note: I'm using Javascript for RegEx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> String should not have more than one space sequentially.

When matching a space, negative lookahead for another space.

> String cannot end with Space.

Also negative lookahead for the end of the string when matching a space:

```
/^([A-Z])([A-Z0-9]| (?! |$)){0,29}$/i
                  ^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Wow! So close yet too far. Thanks for the help mate!

Comment: This is pretty slow way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This regular expression works with Ruby. I assume it will with Javascript as well.

```
r = /^(?!.{31})\p{Alpha}(?:\p{Alnum}| (?! ))*(?<! )$/

"The days of wine and 007"           =~ r  #=> 0   (a match)
"The days of wine and roses and 007" =~ r  #=> nil (too long)
"The days of  wine and 007"          =~ r  #=> nil (two consecutive spaces)
"The days of wine and 007!"          =~ r  #=> nil ('!' illegal)
```

The `\p{}` constructs match Unicode characters.

The regular expression can be expressed as follows in free-spacing mode (in order to document its component parts).

```
/
^            # beginning of string anchor
(?!.{31})    # 31 characters do not follow (neg lookahead)
\p{Alpha}    # match a letter at beg of string
(?:          # begin a non-capture group
  \p{Alnum}  # match an alphanumeric character
  |          # or
  [ ]        # match a space
  (?![ ])    # a space does not follow (neg lookahead)
)*           # end non-capture group and execute >= 0 times
(?<![ ])     # a space cannot precede end of string (neg lookbehind)
$            # end of string anchor
/x           # free-spacing regex definition mode
```

Note that spaces are stripped from regexs defined in free-spacing mode, so spaces that are to be retained must be protected. I've put each in a character class (`[ ]`), but `\s` can be used as well (though that matches spaces, tabs, newlines and a few other characters, which should not be a problem).